# City and District class examples for teaching OOP in PHP

Tags: php, object-oriented

I wrote these two classes for teaching OOP in PHP. Do you think it's breaking some good practices or SOLID principles?

```
<?php

class City
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $districts = [];

    public function __construct($id, string $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function id()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function name():string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function addDistrict(District $district)
    {
        if (!isset($this->districts[$district->id()])) {
            $this->districts[$district->id()] = new District($district->id(), $this, $district->name());
        }
    }

    public function getArray():array
    {
        $districts = [];
        foreach ($this->districts as $district) {
            array_push($districts, $district->getArray());
        }
        return ['id' => $this->id(), 'name' => $this->name(), 'districts' => $districts];
    }

    public function districts():array
    {
        return $this->districts;
    }
}

class District
{
    private $id;
    private $cityId;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($id, City $city, string $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->cityId = $city->id();
    }

    public function getArray():array
    {
        return ['id' => $this->id, 'name' => $this->name];
    }

    public function id()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function name():string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: was the above code written on PHP 7 ? There's enough logical errors in the above code

Comment: can you enlighten me? There were corrections from people. BTW, can I update the code with the corrections?

Comment: The `declare(strict_types=1)` directive must be the first statement in a file (for Scalar Type Hinting)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some questions I'm asking myself related to your chosen design:

- *Why not return type on the `id()` functions* – You have return types on most of the other functions, but why not on either of the `id` functions?
- *Why the `getArray()`?* – This seems like something used by functions like `var_dump()`, but then it would be better to implement [__debug_info](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo), which `var_dump()` could take usage of directly.
- *Possibly rename the private variables* – I'm not sure if php has naming standards, but in my view having both a private variable `name` and a function `name()` seems kind of redundant, and possibly unfortunate. I would possibly rename the variable into `_name` or similar.

### Unfortunate connection between `District` and `City`

In a `City` you might add `Districts`, and each district has links to the id of the cities, making a complete circle. This could be unfortunate, and possibly dangerous. Still you don't have a circular reference as you store only the city id, and not a complete reference to the `City` object.

But I fail to see the good usage of these classes, as they seem to miss any useful methods. Like you can't look up a district and find the corresponding city. Neither can you do anything besides creating or deleting the cities and districts. A good object design would make the object have all needed variables and methods for handling related functions.

Lastly regarding the `addDistrict()` function, I think I would find it natural to allow the `City` class to fully create districts. That is to have `function addDistrict($id, $name)` within `City` class, and then let it create the `District` object.

Comment: thank you for comment. In PHP naming convention forgives this. But you are right. I have to change private names. No useful functions? This is for a section of my next book. Maybe adding those should be better.  As I understood, I have to decouple the district object. I just wanted to show the usage of class types in method params. Why not return type on id functions? Some id's can be int or string like uuid. any ideas? also return types are new at php and they are not obbligatory.
I've should used __toString to return object data as json instead of getArray.

Comment: I think I would use `__debug_info` to return the variables, for use by `var_dump()`, and possibly use `__toString()` to return an html version of the City and/or District. ¨

Comment: @MidoriKocak, To me, sorry to say, I don't think these are good example of using class types in parameters, as I don't understand the usage value.

Comment: check this https://github.com/midorikocak/turkish-cities-districts